# openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory) when using shellcheck

Tags: ubuntu, shellcheck

I am seeing this issue, on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS for shellcheck:

```
$ ls -l /data/myscript
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 1300000013 4200 Aug 25 13:13 /data/myscript
$ shellcheck /data/myscript
/data/myscript: /data/myscript: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Why the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer by reviewing https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1356

The issue in my case was that `snap` blocked access to `/data` (`snap` sandboxes things so it cannot access files outside of home and `/media`), so a simple:

```
mv /data/myscript ~  # Move the script to homedir
shellcheck ~/myscript
```

Made `shellcheck` work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I used `shellcheck` as a pre-commit hook: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck-precommit

Even after adding the repository to the Docker Settings, section File Sharing, to give `shellcheck` access to the folder it didn’t work. I had to quit Docker and start it again…